# Orthogonal and Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to show that if a matrix is orthogonal and triangular, then it is diagonal.

Intuitively, this makes sense, because if it is triangular the only way it can be orthogonal is if the only nonzero entries lie along the diagonal. I think the entries would have to be positive, but how would I prove this?

Comment: Consider the $2\times 2$ matrix where the first column is $e_1$ and the second $-e_2$. Is it orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, but is this the only case, i.e. with +/- 1?

Comment: Do you know that multiplying a vector by an orthogonal matrix doesn't change it's lenght?

Answer (score 2):

An orthogonal matrix has eigenvalues $\pm1$.

The eigenvalues of an upper triangular matrix lie on the diagonal.

For a column to have length $1$, there can be no more nonzero entries other than the one on the diagonal.